# Encrypt e Decrypt em RSA Public_key MOD

Tags: php, rsa

Estou tentando criptografar *strings* em RSA , mas não obtive êxito.

Tentei desta forma (com a lib `phpseclib`):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '...');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'donotcache=153265'.mt_rand(1111111,9999999).'&username=abc'); 
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($data);
$key = $json->{'publickey_mod'};

$privatekey = $key;

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($privatekey);

$plaintext = new Math_BigInteger('teste');
echo $rsa->_exponentiate($plaintext)->toBytes();
```

E este é o retorno:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function abs() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpseclib1.0.11\Math\BigInteger.php:1683 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpseclib1.0.11\Crypt\RSA.php(2194): Math_BigInteger->modPow(NULL, NULL) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpseclib1.0.11\rsa.php(10): Crypt_RSA->_exponentiate(Object(Math_BigInteger)) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpseclib1.0.11\Math\BigInteger.php on line 1683

Queria saber se tem como criptografar/descriptografar de uma forma mais simples, ou de como resolver este erro.

Saída do publickey_mod ($key):

```
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
```

> Lembrando que o publickey_mod muda a cada refresh (post na página)

Comment: Onde está utilizando o método `abs`? Não parece estar no trecho de código que colocou na pergunta.

Comment: é a primeira vez que tento utilizar esta lib, amigo. Não sei onde estou errando. Quero criptografar um texto para RSA utilizando a publickey_mod.